# Xcode 9 simulator timezone can't adjustment & not showing according to timezone in mac OS (10.13)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode9, macos-high-sierra

I update mac os to High Sierra 10.13 & Xcode 9 ,
but have some problem in display simulator timezone.

According to the official documents that the simulator display time is same the mac os timezone.

I try to change pad & phone simulator timezone is different result.

when I change timezone phone is smae the mac os timezone ,
but I change pad timezone always different mac os timezone.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjiQq.jpg)

- macOS High Sierra Version 10.13
- Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235)
- Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-829.6 CoreSimulator-494.13.6)

Comment: Resign is changed in iPhone & iPadin your shared image

Comment: Thanks for reply ,that image is showing timezone problem ,
My mac os timezone is GMT+8 Taipei , 
simulator phone resign set United States but time is same the mac os ;
simulator pad resign set Taiwan but time is different the mac os .

Comment: If resign is changed then time zone will be change

Comment: Yes I think so , but the problem is when I change region but display time is same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve this problem , after I change the simulator version (ios 11.0) that timezone is correct , simulator version (ios 9.0) get problem.